# Is there any easy way to convert images inside a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, png, jpeg

I have a few books that I absolutely MUST be reading; they are a set of calculus textbooks as PDF files. The problem is that the graphs and images in these pdf file are all png, which is apparently not supported by my kindle. Is there anyway I can convert these images as a batch into jpeg or any other format inside the pdf file. I have tried everything from converting the pdf to other formats (equation formatting didn't let it work), to extracting the images from the pdf file and getting them converted. I just really need to know if there is any program I can use to help me or if maybe, there is a way I could 'open' the pdf container, and switch out the png images for the jpeg images and replace the png file extensions with jpg. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The books are:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/CalcI/CalcI_Complete.pdf

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/CalcII/CalcII_Complete.pdf

Comment: This is off topic. See the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq. You should probably find a Kindle forum for help with this.

Comment: Why do you not use converting service from amazon?

Comment: FYI - there are no PNG images in PDF, although there may be images compressed with Flate, similar to PNG.

Answer (score 1):

There is code that can do that using GhostScript (see below).

This fixed the issue for all the broken images fine for me.

If you happen to be one of the few Kindle users with Windows 7/10 64-bit you can try a version of the below bundled with the correct dlls. https://github.com/zifnab87/kindleanpub forked from https://github.com/hmemcpy/kindleanpub. All those can be adapted to older/newer versions of Linux/Macos/Windows

```
#!/bin/sh

# https://github.com/hmemcpy/kindleanpub
# Licensed under the 3-clause BSD license, see LICENSE
#
# Copyright (c) 2018, Igal Tabachnik
# All rights reserved.

# Fixes garbled image rendering from LeanPub PDFs on older Kindle devices (e.g. Kindle DX),
# by recompressing the images using JPEG with highest quality.
# The resulting PDF will be smaller, and will render correctly on Kindle devices.

# Original code by Alfred Klomp, http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/

fix() {
    echo "Converting $IFILE > $OFILE"

    # Converting using high quality, color preserving, 300 dpi imgs
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849325/ghostscript-pdfwrite-specify-jpeg-quality

    gswin64.exe \
        -sOutputFile="$2" \
        -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
        -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
        -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
        -c ".setpdfwrite << /ColorACSImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.08 /Blend 1 >> /ColorImageDownsampleType /Bicubic /ColorConversionStrategy /LeaveColorUnchanged >> setdistillerparams" \
        -f "$1"
}

usage() {
    echo "Reduces PDF filesize by lossy recompressing images to JPEG with Ghostscript."
    echo "Fixes rendering issues with Leanpub PDFs on older Kindle devices."
    echo "  Usage: $1 infile [outfile]"
}

IFILE="$1"

# Need an input file:
if [ -z "$IFILE" ]; then
    usage "$0"
    exit 1
fi

# Output filename defaults to "inputfile-fixed.pdf" unless given:
if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
    OFILE="$2"
else
    OFILE="${IFILE%.pdf}-fixed.pdf"
fi

fix "$IFILE" "$OFILE" || exit $?
```

Example from the original authors:
[image: Before]
[image: After]