# ghostscript pdfwrite specify jpeg quality

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript

I'm trying to concatenate multiple pdf files which basically are the pages of a photobook containing jpg images. For my output pdf file I wish to adjust the image resolution to 300 dpi and I want to keep the best quality. The commands I'm using are:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH ^-dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageResolution=300 ^-dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageResolution=300 ^-dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dMonoImageResolution=300 ^-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dJPEGQ=100 -sOutputFile=out.pdf in1.pdf in2.pdf
```

However, it seems that -dJPEGQ=100 has no effect on the output. Changing this parameter leads to the same filesize and artifacts are visible in the images for all values. Running the command with the option -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer I get better results without artifacts, however this option should also result in 300 dpi. So what is the correct command to specify the quality of the jpg images in the output file?

Comment: The basic answer is 'don't use JPEG'. JPEG is a lossy compression method, and multiple applicaitons tend to interfere with each other which still further reduces quality. If the original is JPEG, then force Flate compression on the output instead of DCT (JPEG). The 'JPEGQ' switch is **specific** to the JPEG device (as noted in te documentation) and so will have no effect with the pdfwrite device. You can adjust the DCT encoding, but you will need to use PostScript to adjust the DCTEncode filter. See the PostScript Language Reference Manual if you want to do this.

Comment: This is a full valid answer I'd think @KenS

Comment: Normally I'd add the info on the DCTEncode filter, but I'm travelling....

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your answer! It made me look deeper and I forced Flate compression by 
`-dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode`. However the print shop didn't like the output size. So I adjusted the DCTEncode filter with follwing commands: 
`gswin64c.exe -sOutputFile=out.pdf -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH ^-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -c ".setpdfwrite << /ColorACSImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.08 /Blend 1 >> /ColorImageDownsampleType /Bicubic /ColorConversionStrategy /LeaveColorUnchanged >> setdistillerparams" -f in1.pdf`

Comment: @tribol That's really awesome! I shrinked a 88 MB file with lossless images to a 26 MB file with lossy, but still high quality images using your settings. 30 MB was my limit and without these custom options, I would only get a 11 MB file with crappy quality images.

Comment: @tribol Could you turn your solution into a an answer? I suppose it will improve readability and help a lot of people (like myself). :)

Comment: nice! It's great to hear that it was also useful to others ;) I turned it now into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is adjusting the DCTEncode filter with follwing commands:

```
gswin64c.exe -sOutputFile=out.pdf -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH ^-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -c "<< /ColorACSImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.08 /Blend 1 >> /ColorImageDownsampleType /Bicubic /ColorConversionStrategy /LeaveColorUnchanged >> setdistillerparams" -f in1.pdf
```

which lead to a compressed file with satisfactory quality for me and can be adjusted to each individual needs.

**Edit:**

the `.setpdfwrite` argument is deprecated for recent ghostscript releases (> 9.50), so I removed it in the answer

Comment: the `-c ".setpdfwrite ...` part of this command doesn't seem to control anything for me. The compression comes from `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress `

Comment: According to [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm) (note 9) The prepress ACS image parameter dictionary is:

`<< /QFactor 0.15 /Blend 1 /ColorTransform 1 /HSamples [1 1 1 1] /VSamples [1 1 1 1] >>`, so I'm noticing a QFactor of 0.15 vs. 0.08 as major difference. Does the file sizes differ at all?

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript seems to have issues reading the /QFactor specified in the -c "..." part for some files. I have tried using this minimal command on my pdf generated by pdflatex for testing:

```bash
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
    -c '<< /ColorACSImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.15 /Blend 1 /ColorTransform 1 >> >> setdistillerparams ' \
    -f input.pdf
```

I find that no matter what /QFactor is specified, the file size and image quality of the output.pdf is the same. I think it is still using the default /QFactor value, which is 0.9.

So I think the only way to specify JPEG quality for pdfwrite is to use a predefined -dPDFSETTINGS to set some QFactor value, and use additional flags to override other settings. The QFactor values for default, ebook, printer and prepress are 0.9, 0.76, 0.4, and 0.15, respectively. See gs document here: [https://www.ghostscript.com/~chrisl/staging/ghostpdl/doc/_build/VectorDevices.html](https://www.ghostscript.com/%7Echrisl/staging/ghostpdl/doc/_build/VectorDevices.html)

Here's what I use for my PDF workflow. (The QFactor of 0.25 doesn't really work though):

```bash
DPI=600
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dFastWebView=true \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dCompressFonts=true \
    -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dDoThumbnails=false -dAutoRotatePages=/None \
    -r$DPI -dColorImageResolution=$DPI -dGrayImageResolution=$DPI -dMonoImageResolution=$DPI \
    -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
    -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
    -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Subsample -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
    -dColorImageFilter=/DCTEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/DCTEncode -dMonoImageFilter=/CCITTFaxEncode \
    -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged -dPassThroughJPEGImages=true \
    -dUseArtBox -dNEWPDF=true -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer \
    -c '<< /ColorACSImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.25 /Blend 1 /ColorTransform 1 >> >> setdistillerparams ' \
    -f input.pdf
```